# How to get URI of a image from web?

Tags: cordova, uri, phonegap-plugins, webintents

I am trying to send an image to whatsapp using web Intent plugin for phonegap. However it requires me to have URI for the image. I have the url for the image it want to share but i don't know how to get the URI, Anyway i can do this?

Using phonegap 3.6

Answer (score 1):

URL is a form of URI so you can use URL.

Comment: yeah, i read that somewhere, but will it work? , whatsapp will load and share image from web? doesn't the image if required to be on the filesystem?